# Session_Start/_End, what happens behind the scenes if they are not included in global?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What happens behind the scenes if you don't explicitly define `Session_Start` and `Session_End` in the global.asax? Does your program just assume that it's there?

Have an internal app I was working on recently who's global didn't have these defined, and the program started having a few session timeout issues. They seemed to be resolved once I added these functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Session_Start` and `Session_End` are just hooks. They are not required and the functionality of sessions is not affected one way or another by whether or not you override them in Global.asax.

I'm not sure what the source of your timeout issues were, but if they were corrected, it was done by whatever you did in those overrides, not by the mere presence of the overloads.

**More technical detail**

I hinted at it above, but I figured I should be more explicit. The class, `System.Web.HttpApplication`, which is derived from in `Global.asax`, has a number of "hooks" defined on it. Essentially, these are just placeholders allowing you inject functionality at key points in time. In other words, when ASP.NET needs to create a session, as part of that action, it calls `Session_Start`. The default implementation does nothing, but if you override it in your derived class, then the code in that override runs.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Chris

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to track the Session start time, you could add a session variable like "SessionStartTime" to Session_Start.